# PHP CLI для работы с файлами на Windows

Tags: php

Подскажите плз в таком вопросе. Я хочу автоматизировать работу с файлами на своем компьютере с помощью PHP CLI. У меня Windows 10. Можно ли поставить отдельно интерпретатор php на Windows 10 или нужно устанавливать только на сервер и в связке с Apache, Mysql? Хочется реализовать это без всяких Open Server и ему подобных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Скачайте с официального сайта http://php.net интерпретатор для Windows. Он в виде zip архива и не требует установки. Распакуйте архив и будет вам интерпретатор. Ещё можете добавить в переменные окружения, чтобы можно было в командной строке вызывать php без полного пути к интерпретатору.

Comment: понял, а mysql потом можно прикрутить к интерпретатору или только в связке с apache надо?

Comment: Можно без связки с apache. Только не будет возможности phpmyadmin использовать. Кстати в php 7 есть встроенный сервер, как им пользоваться также написано на официальном сайте.

Comment: Ок, я понял. Спасибо за ответ!